# Connecting to databases through VPN

Tags: vpn, lamp

We want to create a web application using the usual LAMP stack. However, the app needs to also fetch data from a remote database, and that database can only be connected to if you are inside a VPN.

In the usual scenario, I run a VPN on my desktop, and then any program on my desktop can connect to the remote database.

But I don't know how to make my web server connect to a VPN. The web server has to simultaneously stay available on the open internet as well. If t hat is possible, then our web server app can fetch data from the remote database through the VPN, while service clients on the open web (and using its own local database for additional storage).

(If the answer implies that the web server needs two IP addresses, or even two NICs, that is no problem).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the VPN endpoint device?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If we connect from our desktop, Cisco VPN client is used. I don't know what's on the other end. I just type in the credentials and then my desktop is "in" the VPN, and can connect to network addresses inside the VPN. I'm looking for a way for a program running on the linux server to place itself "in the VPN". Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One server - vpn client, one - server. Mysql will listen on private vpn ip. Another server connects to this ip.

You dont need second ip or nic for that.

It is also possible with ssh tunneling only(Mysql listen localhost). Maybe this is not best variant.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this method either. Do we need to get a command-line Linux version of the VPN software our customer provides with (they provide us with Cisco VPN client to run on our Windows desktops). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, little misunderstand first message.
If you can not change any on server with Mysql and it accessible via CiscoVPN, you can use http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/ on your LAMP server.

Comment: infradead.org/openconnect looks like it will work. Thank you.